# How to connect Raspberry Pi 3 to Visual Studio? (UPDATED)

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging, windows-10-iot-core

I have installed windows 10 IoT core on my Raspberry Pi 3B and connect my raspberry pi and my pc to the same connection. but when I want to run a simple program written in Visual Studio 2022. these errors appear:

```
 Missing tools on -574456429: g++ gdb rsync zip
 Could not resolve path '~/projects/Blink1/obj/ARM/Debug/'
```

the code:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>


// LED Pin - wiringPi pin 0 is BCM_GPIO 17.
// we have to use BCM numbering when initializing with wiringPiSetupSys
// when choosing a different pin number please use the BCM numbering, also
// update the Property Pages - Build Events - Remote Post-Build Event command
// which uses gpio export for setup for wiringPiSetupSys
#define LED 17

int main(void)
{
    wiringPiSetupSys();

    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

    while (true)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);  // On
        delay(500); // ms
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);   // Off
        delay(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

.Windows 10 IoT core version is 10.0.17763.107

.Visual Studio version is 2022 preview

Any idea???

[image]

**UPDATED**: wiring pi is a Linux base library for raspberry pi. so I tried a simple XAML example (a simple Hello world text label). but the error was:

[image]

Comment: I would start with `sudo apt install g++ gdb rsync zip`. Without those packets, it's certainly not going to work.

Comment: @PMF Thanks, the command you mentioned is a Linux terminal command. but here we have Windows 10 IoT core.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I know it works somehow, but I haven't used Windows 10 IoT myself, particularly also because it's not really supported anymore, as it seems. I know some people who might know. I'll ask, but this might take a few days.

Comment: @PMF Thanks a lot. I had to use windows 10 IoT. I really prefer to use a Linux distribution like Raspbian OS instead of windows 10 IoT but I am not allowed.

Comment: I was reading your question not precisely enough - it seems you're using WiringPi. This is asfaik for linux only, and your build seems to require linux dependencies. Are you bound to using C?

Comment: @PMF thanks I got the solution. the problem was the version of the visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the **Visual Studio 2017 Community version** instead of the Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise version (Preview) then the connection problem was solved.